# how to control background audio from Dependecy-service in xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I made a Dependency-Service for playing audio and background control in Xamarin.ios .

Audio was executed in background well.
but, Lockscreen controller was not shown.

I don't know what is problem.

I registered "UIBackgroundMode" and "audio" in "info.plist" 
and set the AVAudioSession as playback.

I used `play_pause(string url)` function for playing audio and setting the `MPNowPlayingInfo`.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AudioService))]

namespace BibleHymn.iOS
{

 class AudioService : IAudio

{

   private bool isPlaying = false;

   private bool interrupted = false;

   int audioNum = 0;

    AVFoundation.AVPlayer player;



public AudioService()
{

     var avSession = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
            avSession.SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.Playback);
            NSError activationError = null;
            avSession.SetActive(true, out activationError);

}

public bool Play_Pause(string url)
{

            if(player == null)
            {

                this.player = new AVFoundation.AVPlayer();
                this.player = AVFoundation.AVPlayer.FromUrl(Foundation.NSUrl.FromString(url));
                this.player.Play();
                UpdateNotification();

            }
                 isPlaying !=isPlaying;
                 return isPlaying;

} 


public void  UpdateNotification()
        {
          var item = new MPNowPlayingInfo
              {
                  Title = "My Title"
              };
              MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.DefaultCenter.NowPlaying = item;

              Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                 UIKit.UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginReceivingRemoteControlEvents();
              });
        }
}
```

I used play_pause from viewModel through button control's command.

init like ...

```
 public IAudio streamService = DependencyService.Get<IAudio>();
```

and in command ...

```
streamService.Play_Pause(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register background support for Audio in the info.plist by following screenshot

[image]
Also did you import Mediaplayer.framework

Comment: Yes ,I already done.
It is equal to "UIBackgroundMode" key and string value as "audio" in xml source mode. also I already imported MediaPlayer in origin code.